# Working with Synology Surveillance Station Web API

Tags: api, synology

If is someone that worked with Synology  API  [documentation is here](https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/DeveloperGuide/Surveillance_Station_Web_API_v2.0.pdf)

I wonder if there is any possibility to get a snapshot picture on a certain timestamp (let's say a snapshot from yesterday). I have all the recordings saved on the server grouped in videos of about ~10 min on a full day.

What I managed to do so far is to get a snapshot of the live screen with this API GET call:

```
http://34.59.110.237:6001/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera&method=GetSnapshot&version=1&cameraId=3&xtamp=1486308916&preview=true&_sid=$currentsid
```

This will get me each time I call it a print of the current screen, somehow the xtamp=1486308916 (unix timestam) won't take any consideration. I tryed with (time,timestamp,update_time), no luck, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The GetSnapshot method from the API SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera ist only for the current view.
I have no idea for your problem, but look at the "List" method from the SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Recording API.